# Python Sphinx/rest substitution for long names defining substitution rule in same source file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution

Post [Python Sphinx referencing long names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034303/python-sphinx-referencing-long-names) provided one answer that was very close to what I was looking for with regards to substitution directives for long class names.

```
def exampleFunction():
    '''Here is an example docstring referencing another
    |ReallyLongExampleClassName|

    .. |ReallyLongExampleClassName| replace:: 
                                    :class:`.ReallyLongExampleClassName`
```

In the example provided however, the definition for replacement rule is within the same pydoc block.  I was hoping to do something like this:

```
"""define all rst links/substitutions used in this file
.. |ReallyLongExampleClassName| replace:: :class:`.ReallyLongExampleClassName`
.. |AnotherExampleClassName| replace:: :class:`.AnotherExampleClassName`
"""

# more code
# more code


def exampleFunction():
    '''Here is an example docstring referencing another
    |ReallyLongExampleClassName|

    # define function
```

Since every file in question is specific, the use of the rst_epilog doesn't extend very well.  Is this even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the variable `rst_epilog` in your `conf.py` file. This is taken straight from [rst_epilog](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-rst_epilog):

> rst_epilog
>
> A string of reStructuredText that will be included at the end of every source file that is read. This is the right place to add substitutions that should be available in every file. An example:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. |psf| replace:: Python Software Foundation
"""
```

But you say that `rst_epilog` is not a good fit for your use case. Perhaps the rst [include directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) is a better approach? You can put your commonly used substitutions into a single rst document and include it in the documents where you need to use them.

Comment: As there is a great deal of uniqueness in each source file on the links they need, the rst_epilog doesn't work as well in our case.  

Also, our pydoc generation work is done behind the scenes.  The contributors to our lib set don't need to worry much about how it's done, they just need to format their pydocs accordingly.  This is in the spirit of trying to keep things simple for them, and as such, we don't expose any of the pydoc config to the standard contributor.

Comment: Perhaps the rst include directive is a better choice. I updated my answer with this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at that but that means user would need to add additional files in support of the documentation.  I was hoping for inline rst of some sort, but it just may not be possible.