# How to cross reference functions in Sphinx without using fully qualified names

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Consider the basic Sphinx RST file

```
.. automodule:: test.submod
   :members:

.. automodule:: test.submod2
   :members:
```

with the following in `conf.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))

extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc'
]

nitpicky = True
```

And a basic module `test` with

```py
# test/__init__.py
from .submod import func
from .submod2 import func2
```

```py
# test/submod.py
def func():
    """
    func docstring
    """
```

```py
# test/submod2.py
def func2():
    """
    func2 docstring

    See also :func:`func`
    """
```

When I build this, I get the warning

```
/home/aaronmeurer/Documents/sphinx-test/test/submod2.py:docstring of test.submod2.func2:3: WARNING: py:func reference target not found: func
```

And if I check the built HTML, the `func` link does not actually link to the `func` docstring.

I tried adding

```py
.. currentmodule:: test
```

to the top of the `index.rst` (see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py:currentmodule), but that doesn't work.

I'd like to be able to cross reference `func` without writing out the fully qualified name `test.submod.func` whenever I link to it (and I'd also prefer if it doesn't show as a fully qualified name in the final HTML).

Comment: Add a dot and it should work: ``See also :func:`.func` ``. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066799/407651.